# Powershell output to text/csv

Tags: powershell, csv, output, text-files

I have a script that runs and outputs ok. But I'm having trouble trying to get the output into a .txt or .csv file.

I used to have a "format-table -auto" on the end, and I tried piping that to the file. But I found you cant pipe the "format-table output".
I'm thinking iI'm m overlooking something. Any help outputting this to a text file would be appreciated.

```
        # Read all the computers from the file
        $computers = get-content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Newfolder\new\input.txt

        # Perform an operation for each row in the file
        foreach ($strComputer in $computers){
        #pulling product key from inside pc
                Get-CimInstance -ClassName SoftwareLicensingProduct -computer $_.Name|
                    where PartialProductKey |
        #labeling table
                    select @{N='Computer';E={$strComputer}},Name,LicenseStatus
            } 
        #output table (1) is good
         Write-Output @{N='Computer';E={$strComputer}},Name,LicenseStatus | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Newfolder\new\output.csv
```

Comment: your code SHOULD be giving you lots of errors. [*grin*] [1] using `$_` [current pipeline object] when NOT in a pipeline. [2] not saving the results of your CIM call so you cannot pass it on to anything OR piping the CIM call output to something that could use it. [3] sending "nothing" to your CSV since you have no connection between the CIM call and the export call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this a little bit, try this out:

```
$computers = get-content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Newfolder\new\input.txt
$Output = @()
foreach ($strComputer in $computers) {
$CimData = Get-CimInstance -ClassName SoftwareLicensingProduct -computer $strComputer | where PartialProductKey 

    if ($CimData) {

        $CimData | % {
        $Row = "" | Select Computer,Name,LicenseStatus
        $Row.Computer = $strComputer
        $Row.Name = $_.Name
        $Row.LicenseStatus = $_.LicenseStatus
        $Output += $Row
        }
    }
} 

$Output | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Newfolder\new\output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

your code has ... many logical problems. see my comments for more info. i decided to simply rewrite it. [*grin*]

this one sets up the source & destination info, what to use when a target system fails to respond, and creates the system list file to work with.

next, it reads the list in, iterates thru that list, uses `try/catch` to handle non-responding systems, calls the CIM class, filters it, and finally hands it off to the `$Results` collection.

after all that, the `$Results` collection is displayed on screen and then sent to a CSV.

```
$SourceDir = $env:TEMP
$SourceFile = 'ComputerList.txt'
$FullSourceFile = Join-Path -Path $SourceDir -ChildPath $SourceFile

$DestDir = $SourceDir
$TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
$DestFile = "ComputerLicenseInfo_$TimeStamp.csv"
$FullDestFile = Join-Path -Path $DestDir -ChildPath $DestFile

$NoResponse = '__NoResponse__'

#region >>> create a file to work with
#    remove this region when ready to work with other sample data OR real data
@'
LocalHost
10.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
BetterNotBeThere
'@ | Set-Content -LiteralPath $FullSourceFile
#endregion >>> create a file to work with

$ComputerList = Get-Content -LiteralPath $FullSourceFile

$Results = foreach ($CL_Item in $ComputerList)
    {
    try
        {
        Get-CimInstance -ClassName SoftwareLicensingProduct -ComputerName $CL_Item -ErrorAction Stop |
            Where-Object {
                $_.PartialProductKey
                } |
            ForEach-Object {
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    ComputerName = $_.GetCimSessionComputerName()
                    Name = $_.Name
                    LicenseStatus = $_.LicenseStatus
                    }
                }
        }
        catch
        {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ComputerName = $CL_Item
            Name = $NoResponse
            LicenseStatus = $NoResponse
            }
        }
    } # end = foreach ($CL_Item in $ComputerList)

# show on screen
$Results

#send to CSV
$Results |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath $FullDestFile -NoTypeInformation
```

screen output ...

```
ComputerName     Name                                LicenseStatus
------------     ----                                -------------
LocalHost        Windows(R) 7, Professional edition              1
10.0.0.1         __NoResponse__                     __NoResponse__
127.0.0.1        Windows(R) 7, Professional edition              1
BetterNotBeThere __NoResponse__                     __NoResponse__
```

CSV file content ...

```
"ComputerName","Name","LicenseStatus"
"LocalHost","Windows(R) 7, Professional edition","1"
"10.0.0.1","__NoResponse__","__NoResponse__"
"127.0.0.1","Windows(R) 7, Professional edition","1"
"BetterNotBeThere","__NoResponse__","__NoResponse__"
```